# How do I remove an attribute (directive) dependent on whether something exists?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs

I want to remove `[tooltip]` if the value given for the text does not exist.

```
<ng-template #lSelector [formGroup]="form">
  <selectorf
    class="selector"
    formControlName="label"
    [tooltip]="this.form.controls.l.value"
  >
  </selectorf>
```

if "this.form.controls.l.value" is null, remove tooltip.

Comment: [tooltip]="this.form.controls.l.value ? this.form.controls.l.value : '' "
Single quotes after the colon(:)

Comment: the issue with this is that the tooltip is still there, it just shows up blank. I want a way I can completely remove the tooltip

Comment: Maybe you can extract out the tooltip to two spans and then based on the value you can conditionally print?

Comment: or instead of '', you can try null too

Comment: tried setting it to null, it doesnt work either and also tried the two spans it completely removes my selector

Comment: Did you try putting both spans inside the selector?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this,

```
[tooltip]="this.form.controls.l.value ? this.form.controls.l.value : null"
```

Comment: does not work the tooltip is still there, just blank

Answer (score 0):

It is not an elegant solution but could you use an *ngIf like this:

```js
<ng-template #lSelector [formGroup]="form">
  <selectorf *ngIf="this.form.controls.l.value"
    class="selector"
    formControlName="label"
    [tooltip]="this.form.controls.l.value"
  >
  </selectorf>
   <selectorf *ngIf="!this.form.controls.l.value"
    class="selector"
    formControlName="label"
  >
  </selectorf>
```